# Python/ipywidgets functions that links multiple widgets in different functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, widget, ipywidgets

I am looking a for simple function that can link dynamically the 2 functions below, so that by changing the value of D or R, A will change accordingly.

```
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets

dW = widgets.Dropdown(options=['2', '1'])
rW = widgets.FloatText(200)
aW = widgets.FloatText()  

@interact(D=dW, R=rW)
def print_p(D, R):
    dW = D
    rW = R 
    
@interact(A=aW)
def prin_t(A):
    aW.value = int(dW.value) * int(rW.value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `interact` is causing some confusion here, why not use a standard `observe` call for both dW and rW?

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

dW = widgets.Dropdown(options=['2', '1'])
rW = widgets.FloatText(200)
aW = widgets.FloatText()

def change_a(_):
    aW.value = int(dW.value) * int(rW.value)

dW.observe(change_a)
rW.observe(change_a)

display(widgets.VBox(children=[dW, rW, aW]))
```